# Vb.net checkbox won't load from text file

Tags: vb.net, loading

I attempted to load a checkbox from a text file in VB.NET as a part of the settings form for my application. I used this piece of code:

```
Sub loadfiles()
    Dim read As System.IO.StreamReader

    read = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\Public\Documents\procrastinGONEnotif.txt")
    Dim text As String = read.ReadToEnd()
    read.Close()
    If text = "false" Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
    Else
        If text = "true" Then
            CheckBox1.Checked = True
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The file saving code is right here:

```
Dim write As System.IO.StreamWriter
write = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\Public\Documents\procrastinGONEnotif.txt", False)
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    write.WriteLine("true")
Else
    write.WriteLine("false")
End If
write.Close()
```

The file is supposed to load when the form starts and save when I press a button. However, the form does not load the file even though it is present and contains "true" or "false". Instead, the code detects it as "neither true or false" and sends the message "ERROR!", which I added to the application to test if it actually read the file.

Comment: set a breakpoint and debug it; also if there is just one setting, consider looking into `My.Settings`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you read/write the value `false`. There is a newline character after `false` in the output file, which is visible when you open the text file or initially read it into `text`. An easy solution to this is to simply use `read.ReadToEnd().Trim()` to remove the extra whitespace characters.

You can also combine your nested `If...Else` into `If...ElseIf...Else` to make your code less confusing.

```
Sub loadfiles()
    Dim read As System.IO.StreamReader
    read = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\Public\Documents\procrastinGONEnotif.txt")
    Dim text As String = read.ReadToEnd().Trim()
    read.Close()
    If text = "false" Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
    ElseIf text = "true" Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = True
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your entire code to this

For loading:

```
CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("FILE_PATH"))
```

For saving

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("FILE_PATH", Convert.ToString(CheckBox1.Checked))
```